# save as method of workbook class failed - Outlook vba

Tags: vba, outlook

i am trying to save the outlook mail attachment file (single file) with xlsx file format but below code showing error `Save as Mehtode of workbook class failed` in the line of `wb.saveAs`. need someone help.

```
 Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
        Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
        Dim objExcel As Object
        Dim wb As Object
        Dim saveFolder As String, dateFormat As String, fName As String
        saveFolder = "D:\Ashok\Work\Capital\Collection\"

        For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
        sFileName = LCase(objAtt.FileName)

            sPathName = saveFolder & sFileName
            objAtt.SaveAsFile sPathName


    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
            Set wb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(sPathName)

' error on below line

            wb.SaveAs FileName:=Replace(sPathName, ".csv", ".xlsx"), FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook 
                wb.Close SaveChanges:=True


            Kill sPathName
            objExcel.Quit

    Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: I have not tried so this is a guess.  You are changing the extension from CSV to XLSX.  But a CSV file is not a workbook.  The Windows default is for Excel to open CSV files as though they were workbooks so why not leave the extension alone.

Answer (score 0):

finally i got the answer : adding `microsoft excel library` in the tool and defined `wb as workbook`

Comment: From what I can see the only reason to add the library is so that Outlook knows what `xlOpenXMLWorkbook` means.  If you'd used `wb.SaveAs FileName:=Replace(sPathName, ".csv", ".xlsx"), FileFormat:=51` your original code would have worked.  In these cases I usually open the Immediate window in Excel,  type `?xlOpenXMLWorkbook`  and it returns the number I need to use.